# Geometric Arthur-Selberg

Tags: automorphic-forms, geometric-representation-theory

What should be the analogue of [the Arthur-Selberg trace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur%E2%80%93Selberg_trace_formula) in the geometric Langlands theory?